# how to convert image in a byte[] array to Xamarin.IOS UIImage control

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage

My Xamarin.IOS app gets build error: "cannot convert type byte[] to UIKit.UIImage"

My code:

```
ImageView_camera.Image =         Camera_Socket_Client.packet_frame_state.buffer;
```

The buffer contains a frame sent by socket from a UWP Windows app, which got the frame from a USB camera from a Logitech HD 1080p webcam.

I want to show live image from webcam at IPAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(myByteArray));
```

Comment: Yep.  And my missing step has been to first convert data to PNG, then upload to IOS.  In progress...