# CollectionViewController using c# displays with black background, no images

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm not at all familiar with collection views so please bear with me.  I have a `DataSet` of images that I need to display in a 2 column grid.  I'm guessing that the code below won't do that, but until I can get it to display ANY images, it will be difficult for me to figure out how to get the two columns.  Right now, when I execute the code below, all I get is a view with a black background and nothing else.

My code:

*** The Collection View Controller ***

```
class ParticipantViewController : UICollectionViewController
{
    static NSString participantCellId = new NSString("ParticipantCell");

    public ParticipantViewController(UICollectionViewLayout layout, DataSet pParticipants) : base(layout)
    {
        Participants = pParticipants;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(ParticipantCell), participantCellId);

    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return Participants.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var participantCell = (ParticipantCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(participantCellId, indexPath);

        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])Participants.Tables[0].Rows[indexPath.Row]["Photo"];

        UIImage Mybitmap = GetImagefromByteArray(imageBytes);

        participantCell.Image = Mybitmap;

        return participantCell;
    }

    public override void ItemHighlighted(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
        cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
    }

    public override void ItemUnhighlighted(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
        cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    }

    public override bool ShouldHighlightItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool ShouldShowMenu(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanPerformAction(UICollectionView collectionView, Selector action, NSIndexPath indexPath, NSObject sender)
    {
        // Selector should be the same as what's in the custom UIMenuItem
        if (action == new Selector("custom"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override void PerformAction(UICollectionView collectionView, Selector action, NSIndexPath indexPath, NSObject sender)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("code to perform action");
    }

    // CanBecomeFirstResponder and CanPerform are needed for a custom menu item to appear
    public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override void WillRotate(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)
    {
        base.WillRotate(toInterfaceOrientation, duration);

        var lineLayout = CollectionView.CollectionViewLayout as LineLayout;
        if (lineLayout != null)
        {
            if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown))
                lineLayout.SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(400, 0, 400, 0);
            else
                lineLayout.SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(220, 0.0f, 200, 0.0f);
        }
    }
    public static UIImage GetImagefromByteArray(byte[] imageBuffer)
    {
        NSData imageData = NSData.FromArray(imageBuffer);
        return UIImage.LoadFromData(imageData);
    }

}
```

**** The cell code ****

```
class ParticipantCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    UIImageView imageView;
    public UIImage Image;

    [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public ParticipantCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        BackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0) };

        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };

        ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
        ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        ContentView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.8f, 0.8f);

        imageView = new UIImageView();
        imageView.Image = Image;
        imageView.Center = ContentView.Center;
        imageView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.7f, 0.7f);

        ContentView.AddSubview(imageView);
    }
}
```

**** The code that calls the collection view controller ****

```
DataSet theParticipants = myService.GetPhotos(Myuser.Username, Myuser.Password, company, department, section);
vc = new ParticipantViewController(new LineLayout(), theParticipants) { };
this.ShowViewController(vc, this);
```

It all compiles and executes, the dataset has 3 images (rows) in it, yet nothing is displayed.  I know I probably don't have this coded correctly, but I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong.

***** Update ******

Corrected my code to convert the data stored in the `DataSet` from `byte[]` to `Image`.  Same results though, black screen, no image.

Comment: what is the data type of `Participants.Tables[0].Rows[indexPath.Row]["Photo"]`?

Comment: @Jason the data type is byte stored in a blob.

Comment: you can't just cast a blob of data to a `UIImage`.  Assuming the blob represents some valid image data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890842/how-to-convert-image-in-a-byte-array-to-xamarin-ios-uiimage-control

Comment: Duh ... and I knew that ... I have code that coverts it.

Comment: @jason Corrected my code ... same result ...

Comment: @Jason it seems that GetCell isn't being called and I have no idea why ....

Comment: offhand, I'm not sure.  I'd look over the 2 sample apps here to see what you may have missed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview

Comment: @Jason That's the example I used to create this code ... lol ....

Comment: @PrescottChartier Hi ,not suggesting to use the sample project to test that , the sample is created by previous version of Visual Studio . If have time you can share a new create sample project link here , I will check that .

Comment: please direct your replies at the correct person

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT I don't understand, I created my collection view controller using the code in the link provided as a guide and when I run my code GetCell is never called, I don't know what you mean when you say "share a new create sample project link here , I will check that". You want me to ask a new question with the subject GetCell isn't called? I'm confused.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Hi , sorry for misunderstanding . Not need to ask a new question , just mean that need a new created repository link such as in github . Then I will download that to test in local site :-)